# C# Dragging Buttons in an Area

Tags: c#

I have a homework from school and im stuck.

I must do a program like " http://www.beyinsporu.com/kelime-zinciri.php " this game.

As you can see there some buttons in-line and they make a word and 2 more letter at the bot.

In the game, you must drag buttons behind the other word and a new word will create.

For Example;

You have " add " word in the screen and you  "h", "e" buttons.

After this you have drag "h" and "e" buttons before the "add" word and it must detect "head" word.

The problem is how can i detect is any button dragged in correct area ?.

I hope you can understand my English ^_^ if you not, please tell me to correct it.

It's Windows Form. Microsoft visual Studio 2010.

My button dragging codes;

```
  bool dragging = false;
  Point first;  
  private void button23_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = true;
        first = e.Location;
    }
    private void button23_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragging == true)
        {

            button23.Left = e.X + button23.Left - (first.X);
            button23.Top = e.Y + button23.Top - (first.Y);
        }
    }
    private void button23_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;

    }
```

Comment: is this in windowsForm App or WebSite?

Comment: WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms, Console? Drag and drop snapping? Fancy animations? FAR more details AND proof of effort.

Comment: It is windows Form, im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is how can i detect is any button dragged in correct area ?"

Add some Panels to your Form to indicate valid drop zones.  When a "button" (I wouldn't use an actual Button for this) is dropped in a Panel you can "snap" it into the correct position.  Since the Panels are in pre-determined locations, you can simply iterate over them and determine what letter(s) are in them (if any) to build up the current word being proposed by the user.

How are you currently implementing the movement of your "buttons"?  Are you using classic [Drag/Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx) functionality?...or are you literally updating the location of the buttons in response to being dragged?  Show us some code...